# Mysql - Duplicated row only in output

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop, duplicate-data

I tired to select only one name from a table but the problem is the output is duplicated 3 or 4 times with same result for e.g ( in phpmyadmin there only 5 row when I call it the output duplicated the 5 row be a 20 row

this is code that I used

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM attendance, users ";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $status = $row['status'];
    $notes = $row['notes'];
    $datetime= $adminfunctions->displayDate($row['timestamp']);
    echo "<tr><td><a href='" . $configs->getConfig('WEB_ROOT') . "admin/adminuseredit.php?usertoedit=" . $row['username'] . "'>" . $row['student_name'] . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td><div class='shorten'><a href='#'>" . $status . "</a></div></td><td>" . $notes . "</td><td>" . $datetime . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='text-center'><div class='btn-group btn-group-xs'><a href='".$configs->getConfig('WEB_ROOT')."admin/adminuseredit.php?usertoedit=".$row['username']."' title='Edit' class='open_modal btn btn-default'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> View</a>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

I want to remove this duplicated result and select only for e.g John Doe when I got to his profile only show his attendance

Comment: You need to properly `JOIN` your tables: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Comment: use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`

Comment: @jeroen I will see that link

Comment: used DISTINCT but same thing i'll try  GROUP BY @MySQLRockstar

Comment: GROUP BY worked thanks @MySQLRockstar any ideas how I can select only result for selected user ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` both tables using an inner join. Presumably your "users" table will have a primary key that will join to a foreign key on the "attendance" table, something like "student_id".

```
WHERE users_id = students_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if your users have an ID, and before calling the SQL query you know the ID of the user for which you want the attendance you can change your SQL query to

`SELECT * FROM Users U JOIN Attendance A on U.id = A.user_id where U.id = [insert userid]`

Think that was it, but this is just off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicatew because you are doing a select statement for two tables (User and Attendance). The User table will have a primary key (user_id) and the attendance table will have a foreign key (user_id). You need to join them using this foreign key relationship, as follows:

```
Select * from User u JOIN     Attendance a ON u.user_id = a.user_id;
```

This will give you the rows in both tables where the users are the same.

I hope this helps.